# Rails form create is submitting to update after validation errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, form-for

My form works when creating a new job, but when I submit the form and it has validation errors (and try re-submitting the form) it seems to go to the update method in my controller (which throws `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` because there is no ID set).

My controller:

```
class JobsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @job = Job.new
  end

  def edit
    @job = Job.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @job = Job.new(params[:job])

    if @job.save
      redirect_to @job, :notice => 'Job was successfully created.'
    else
      render :action => "new"
    end
  end

  def update
    @job = Job.find(params[:id])

    if @job.update_attributes(params[:job])
      redirect_to @job, :notice => 'Job was successfully updated.'
    else
      render :action => "edit"
    end
  end
end
```

My form:

```
<%= form_for(@job) do |f| %>
  #...
<%= f.submit %>
```

On the validation error page, this is what the tag gets rendered as (even though this job never got inserted into the database and I was originally trying to create a new job):

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/jobs/10" class="edit_job" id="edit_job_10" method="post">
```

Update - here is my routes.rb and new.html.erb:

```
Myapp::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :jobs
end
```

And my new view has this:

```
<h2>New Job</h2>
<%= render 'form' %>
```

Edit has the same `render 'form'`

Comment: On validation page is there any hidden fields `_method` inside the form?

Comment: Yes - this is on the failed validation form for creating a new job.

<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="put" />

Comment: then this is the reason. but wondering why it would come when validation occurs! let me check if i can help you

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure what is causing it =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to figure out what the problem was.  I was calling `update_attributes` in my model, which causes the Job to be saved (and deleted shortly after).

This made `form_for` think the item was being updated and was causing the problems when trying to update something that didn't really exist.  I just switched over to using `assign_attributes` which doesn't save anything.

Comment: Thanks for answering your own question - this just solved a huge headache!

Answer (score 0):

where is your form on?, it is on the page `new.html.erb` or `edit.html.erb`? Put your form in the right place, and the form will know what action it have to do. In the case you want your above form create new job, add this and try create new job again:

```
<%= form_for (@job, url: jobs_path) do |f| %>
```

Comment: The form is on new.html.erb, and it does work properly until I try submitting the form when it has validation errors.  When that happens, the form loads under new.html.erb again, but this time the action seems to think it's doing an update (the submit button even has "Update Job" instead of "Create Job"

Comment: so, you need to specify path to create new job for form, try my answer and check result. And can you show your routes?

Comment: Sure - see above for my routes

Comment: it does not matter in which view you are on. `form_for` will check `@object.new_record?` to identify if it's new or exiting record and hence should add `post` or `put` accordingly.